# jquery textarea append does not work after the textarea has been reset with val("")

Tags: jquery, textarea

I am able to successfully append to a textarea element like the following:

```
jQuery("#edit-submitted-document-requests_mine").append("ITEM_0: selected \n\r");
```

but then I empty out the textarea with the following:

```
jQuery("#edit-submitted-document-requests_mine").val("");
```

this works in that the textarea is now empty but if I do another append like:

```
jQuery("#edit-submitted-document-requests_mine").append("ITEM_0: selected \n\r");
```

then this data is not added.

Why does jquery textarea append not work after the textarea has been reset with `val("")`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure why `.append()` acts that way, but you might want to always set the value using `.val()`. You can append like this:

```
jQuery("#edit-submitted-document-requests_mine").val(function(index, value) {
    return value + "ITEM_0: selected \n\r";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can append with `val()`

```
 jQuery("#edit-submitted-document-requests_mine").val(function(i,v){ 
                       return v +  "ITEM_0: selected \n\r");
  });
```

Comment: That won't *append*, it'll *replace*.

Comment: oo yes...damn!!! i think i better go for a coffee now....anyways thanks.. updated.... :)